# Include only columns from DataFrame that I specify in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Okay, so I have a DataFrame with stock data. I want the DataFrame to only include information about the stocks that I include in a list and not show data for other tickers that are not included in my list. I would rather not manually write down which tickers I want by doing:

`dataframe[['Apple','MSFT','etc.']]`

I tried doing this:

`dataframe[[myportfolio]]`

but had no success.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "A DataFrame with stock data" is a bit vague.  Can you show what it contains and the data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `myportfolio` is a list of strings then this will return only the columns with names in the list:

```
dataframe[myportfolio]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the ticker is a column value. If that is the case you can use this:

```
dataframe[dataframe.ticker.isin(myportfolio)]
```

Where `ticker` is the column name of the ticker symbols, and `myportfolio` is your ticker symbol list.

**Example:**

---

```
dataframe= pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['abc', 'def','hij','klm'], 'open': ['1','2','3','4'], 'close':['5','6','7','8']})
myportfolio=['abc','klm']
```

| ticker | open | close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 5 |
| def | 2 | 6 |
| hij | 3 | 7 |
| klm | 4 | 8 |

```
dataframe[dataframe.ticker.isin(myportfolio)]
```

| ticker | open | close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 5 |
| klm | 4 | 8 |